# Can someone apply for a Masters in Computer Science having two years Associate degree and professional experince in programing

Tags: graduate-admissions

If someone has a associate's degree with relevant courses (math and physics) and more than 10 years of (verifiable) programming experience, is it generally possible to apply for graduate admission at a good international university?

Comment: What do you mean by "overcome the career growth issues"?

Comment: Hi, I've migrated this question to Academia as it is about graduate admissions, and not about how to teach Computer Science.  Good luck, and I hope you find your answers!

Comment: The real (albeit unhelpful) answer is that you'll have to check particular programs you're interested in and see whether they require a bachelor's degree. I suspect that [virtually] all will -- there is no "fast track" for programmers that I'm aware of. So, you may want to search for efficient ways to get your BS and/or MS [though, this site does not allow "shopping questions", so you'll have to do this search elsewhere]. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in most places, you can *apply* to a program. But that doesn't mean that you will necessarily be admitted. In some places a bachelor's degree might be required for graduate study, but in those places, I assume that exceptions can be made but only for exceptional cases.

For any application, for an academic program or for a job, you will need to make your own case as to your suitability and likelihood of success. But even then, you can expect a lot of competition, most of it from people whose qualifications are easier to evaluate. So you need a strong case.

In particular, without an undergraduate degree, people will suspect that there are gaps in your education. Being a "programmer" doesn't, of itself, fill any of those gaps. So you will either need to demonstrate competence, or obtain it to be successful.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, generally no, but what you could do is look into combination bs/ms programs, of which there are many. In those programs you generally start taking graduate courses in your last year of college, and they save a year of graduate work. Of course you will always want to speak to someone from the specific program to know how your combination of AA or AS courses and potential life experience credits (or the ability to test out of certain courses via a challenge test) will work there.

Comment: I wouldn't be quite so discouraging about the US, actually. But the advice is good.